# Why doesn't visibility affect Rust's orphan rule?

Tags: rust, traits, orphan-rule

I'm working on a Rust project where I have a trait defined with `pub(crate)` visibility. When I try to implement a foreign trait for types that implement my local, crate-private trait, the compiler complains about violating the orphan rule. Here's a minimal example:

```rust
// Inside my crate
pub(crate) trait MyLocalTrait {
    // ...
}

// serde is a dependency, so Serialize is a "foreign" trait
impl<T: MyLocalTrait> serde::Serialize for T {
    // ...
}
```

My understanding is that since `MyLocalTrait` is only visible within my crate, the only types that could implement it would also have to be local. Shouldn't this be enough to satisfy the orphan rule, since there's no chance of a foreign type implementing `MyLocalTrait`? Is this a limitation in the current implementation of the orphan rule, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What if some other crate defined a trait, implemented it for some of the same types you did, and tried to define the same blanket impl for Serialize?

Answer (score 3):

After thinking about it for a little bit, it became obvious why this is not allowed. While `pub(crate)` makes is so that a foreign crate can't implement `MyLocalTrait`, that doesn't exclude my local crate from implementing it for a foreign type:

```rust
// Inside my crate
pub(crate) trait MyLocalTrait {
    // ...
}

// Also inside my crate
impl MyLocalTrait for SomeForeignType {
    // ...
}

// Error because `serde::Serialize` is now implemented for `SomeForeignType`, violating the orphan rule
impl<T: MyLocalTrait> serde::Serialize for T {
    // ...
}
```